# Going down theorem

Tags: commutative-algebra

Here $A$ is a commutative ring with unity.

> How to show that going down theorem holds for $A$ contained in $A[x]$, the polynomial ring.

Lying over is ok. I cannot do the other part.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at a commutative algebra text like Atiyah Macdonald (where this is either proved or an exercise, I bet)?

Answer (score 1):

Going down holds for arbitrary flat extensions, a proof can be found in every book on commutative algebra, or in the Stacks project [Lemma 9.36.17](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00HS), or at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Going_up_and_going_down).

But for $A \to A[x]$ it's almost trivial: We have $\mathfrak{p} \subseteq \mathfrak{p}' \subseteq A$ and $\mathfrak{q}' \subseteq A[x]$ lying over $\mathfrak{p}'$. Then $\mathfrak{q}:=\mathfrak{p}[x]$ is a prime ideal lying over $\mathfrak{p}$ satisfying $\mathfrak{q} \subseteq \mathfrak{q}'$

Comment: Why is q contained in q(prime)?

Comment: Try to prove it yourself.